# GGPlot reduce Opacity of Lineplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am quite new to R. I have the following code and I have figured out I can lower the opacity of lines on a line plot using alpha but I only want to reduce the opacity of certain lines. For example I want the grey lines to be more transparent but the 3 coloured lines to remain vibrant. I have tried a few different methods but they all seem to break.

```
ggplot(IRL_counties_Covid19, aes(x=TimeStamp, y=ConfirmedC, group=CountyName, color=CountyName)) +
  geom_line(size=1.5, alpha = 0.1) +
  xlab("Date") + ylab("Cumulative Cases") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma, breaks = seq(0, 250000, 25000)) +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b %Y", date_breaks = "1 month") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Galway" = "orange", "Dublin" = "green", "Leitrim" = "purple", 
                                rep("grey", length(unique(IRL_counties_Covid19$CountyName))-1)), 
                     breaks = c("Galway", "Dublin", "Leitrim")) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 3))) +
  ggtitle("Cumulative COVID-19 Cases by County in Ireland (Sep 2021 - Mar 2023)")
```

Comment: Add `scale_alpha_manual(values=c(1,1,1,0.3))`

Answer (score 1):

Set `alpha=` within a `aes`thetic (with a variable) and then control it with `scale_alpha_manual`. Since you want to set it to hard values for specific lines, it should be a discrete variable, one of `character` or `factor`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp, group = cyl, alpha = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c("4"=1, "6"=0.3, "8"=0.8))
```

[image: ggplot2 with variable alpha/opacity]